# Pymongo and updating records

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a dataset that I am pulling from an API. The dataset contains fields such as store_id, store_description, monthly_sales, total_sales.

There are 16,219 records in this dataset

I would like to automate the pulling of this data but when I pull from the API more than once I get duplicate records of the data instead of each record being updated. Below is the code I am using to update the data:

```
for i in json.loads(data):
    for j in col.find({}):
        if i['store_id'] == j['store_id']:
            col.update_one({j}, {i})
        else:
            col.insert_one({i})
```

I am not really sure what exaclty I am doing wrong here. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is to match on a key of `store_id` and update the entirety of the record if it matches an existing record, or insert it if it doesn't, then use `replace_one()` with `upsert=True`, i.e.:

```
col.replace_one({'store_id': i['store_id']}, i, upsert=True)
```